# how to detect the jquery UI Dialog box element by using WATIR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, testing, watir, watir-webdriver

I am very new to using `WATIR`. I am writing some small scripts to test and its very cool. I have a `Jquery UI Dialog box` for the User Sign Up. So, the Dialog box has `Username text-box`, `password text-box` and `submit button`. But I could not click the submit button. I could not detect any element inside the Dialog box. Please someone advice me to pass over this.

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
require "watir-webdriver/extensions/alerts"

if browser.button(name: "commit").exists?
#then browser.button(name: "commit").click
then browser.javascript_dialog.button(name: "commit").click
puts " Dialog box Detected"
else puts " Failed"
puts " Dialog box is not Detected"
end
```

Its shows the Failed and the Dialog box is not Detected..

Here is the example of what i need to do... 
[Modal Example](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) I need to find any elements in the dialog box.
Thanks..

Comment: Please provide link to the page, a similar one or relevant HTML.

Comment: Thanks Zeljko, I updated the link in my question. Thanks   http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: If I tried each line in the command prompt, its working... but if i run the .rb file, after the popup opened its showing error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements that you want to interact with are in a frame. This clicks "Create new user" button:

```
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto "http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form"
browser.frame(:class => "demo-frame").button(:id => "create-user").click
```

Comment: Could you tell me, As a beginner, I am strucking a lot. Where shall i get the source code examples.. or could anybody is teaching on how to use it? Please advice me...

Comment: If you get stuck, ask here. There is a lot of documentation at http://watir.com/ and http://watirwebdriver.com/. There are also two books on Watir: http://watir.com/book/